# Unable to open file 'STDCTRLS.OBJ'

Tags: delphi, delphi-2009

First of all, sorry for my bad english.

I started with Delphi today, created a simple form example named test.

```
unit teste;

interface

uses
  Windows, Messages, SysUtils, Variants, Classes, Graphics, Controls, Forms,
  Dialogs, StdCtrls;

type
  TForm2 = class(TForm)
    Edit1: TEdit;
    Label1: TLabel;
  private
    { Private declarations }
  public
    { Public declarations }
  end;

var
  Form2: TForm2;

implementation

{$R *.dfm}

end.
```

I searched at google, then here and did not find an answer for this problem, I´m not able to run it, because the logs return these errors:

```
[ILINK32 Error] Fatal: Unable to open file 'STDCTRLS.OBJ'
```

I had no idea how to fix it, could you help me?

Thanks!
best regard´s.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks like you've created a C++Builder project, but written/pasted in Delphi code. Delphi doesn't use `ILINK` at all, and it doesn't use `STDCTRLS.OBJ` (it would complain about `StdCtrls.dcu` instead).

Since you have no functional code in the project, I'd just start over. Use `File|Close All`, and don't save changes. Then use `File|New|VCL Forms Application - Delphi for Win32`, and hit <kbd>F9</kbd> to see if you can run that project.

Comment: Would the downvoter care to explain why? `ILINK` is the C++ linker, and therefore isn't used for Delphi projects, and Delphi doesn't use `STDCTRLS.OBJ` in any way, shape, or form; it's a C++ object file.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the IDE's search paths are configured correctly, and that the project has correct references to the RTL and VCL packages.